# DNS resolution stops working on some networks

Tags: wireless, networking, dns

I am running Kubuntu 14.10 and am having problems with DNS resolution.

On my home network there is no problem at all.

However, at my college, I usually get about 10 sec of working internet before it stops working. I am still connected to the wireless access point but I cannot `ping` or `dig` anything.

Normally I have to stop WICD (which I am running - my problems are worse with NM) and reload the network card modules to get back up and running again - for another 10 secs!

Sometimes the internet works again after about 5 mins or so, but it's quite temperamental.

Any thoughts as to how to troubleshoot and fix?

Comment: Talk to your network administrator at your school. My guess is either a proxy or firewall. Some networks require login.

Answer (score 0):

Start by querying the network adapter to see how the connection is setup:

> ifconfig -a

make sure you have a DNS server specified, as an IP address, and that the adapter is using DHCP to get this information. If no DNS server is specified (field is blank), then you are not getting an appropriate answer from your DHCP server at college, and should contact their helpdesk.